# Java Calculator char thread

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner, calculator

This is my void main in my code. When I compile the code it shows no errors, But when I type any random letters then it shows the following thread.

Output:

```
Please enter the equation :
2323.10ffxcv
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at Calculator.main(calculator.java:31)
```

[This is the output in CMD.][1]

Code:

```
Calculator calc = new Calculator();
Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the equation : ");

double a = numbers.nextDouble();
char sign = numbers.next().charAt(0);
double b = numbers.nextDouble();

switch (sign) {
case '+':
    calc.add(a, b);
    break;
case '-':
   calc.sub(a, b);
   break;
case '*':
    calc.multiply(a, b);
    break;
case '/':
    calc.divide(a, b);
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Sorry I ( The program ) did not understand");

    while (sign != '+' || sign != '-' || sign != '*' || sign != '/') {
        switch (sign) {
        case '+':
            calc.add(a, b);
            break;
        case '-':
            calc.sub(a, b);
            break;
        case '*':
            calc.multiply(a, b);
            break;
        case '/':
            calc.divide(a, b);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry I ( The program ) did not understand");
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Problem located in your 31 number line of `calculator.java`

Comment: Its a runtime exception telling you there is an input mismatch. Inputting letters to calculate something is breaking your application as would be expected. Working as intended in my opinion.

Comment: It happens because you are trying to read doubles with `numbers.nextDouble();` but providing letters instead. You can either put that on a try/catch block to catch invalid inputs, or use `nextLine()` and validate the `String` yourself.

Comment: but will it validate the string using `switch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Scanner` class won't tokenize your input the way you seem to assume.  That is, `numbers.nextDouble()` doesn't read up until the end of the first bit of data that looks like a `Double`.  It reads *the entire line*, and attempts to parse it as a `Double`.  You get an `InputMismatchException` because the input (`2323.10ffxcv`) doesn't match the expected data type (`Double`).

You need to find a way to either tokenize the string yourself, or simply enter each  value on its own line.  Even so, the last part of your input (`ffxcv`) is still going to break things, because it can't be parsed as a `Double`.

Comment: Then should I change the datatype to `string` (`numbers.nextLine`) ?

Comment: @KaranGandhi It would help to know what you're trying to do.  `2323.10ffxcv` isn't even a valid equation.  What are you expecting to happen when you give that input?

Comment: When I type or do some mistake it should print `Sorry I did not understand what you are saying`

Comment: @KaranGandhi, When a scanner is unable to parse your input, it throws an exception.  So to be able to handle the case of bad input, you need to surround the relevant parts of your code with a try/catch block, where the desired error output is done in the catch statement.